How can I run Firefox over the same running instance but in two different WAYLAND_DISPLAY?
I'm testing a new wayland compositor and debugging some rendering issues. To test this, I'm switching to a different TTY, starting compositor B and then trying to open a new Firefox window there; I do it this way so I can realize if my rendering issues are related to compositor A, to Firefox, or to Wayland itself.
In a Xorg server it's possible to achieve this by specifying the server running on a different display, e.g.
[user@host ~]$ DISPLAY=:0 firefox

And
[user@host ~]$ DISPLAY=:1 firefox

I tried to achieve this in a similar fashion for Wayland, i.e.
[user@host ~]$ WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-2 firefox

But it doesn't work as Firefox windows keeps opening in the first Wayland compositor I execute it. I couldn't find any references to other variables that can achieve this but WAYLAND_DISPLAY, and webpages only talk about this one and copypaste this exact same post over the net.
Maybe there is some another environment variable and I'm setting the wrong one? Or is this even possible in Wayland?

AFAIK it has nothing to do with Wayland (or X11 if that's the case). It's just many programs are not designed to support spawning windows in multiple "displays". IIRC when with X11 you can have firefox run as the same user and spawn windows in multiple displays only if you use a separate Firefox profile per display (basically separate "process" per display, I think). Might work in the case of Wayland too, but perhaps not what you want.
